# how to prevent some columns from being highlighted when selecting a row

Tags: highlighting, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a semi-dynamically created window ( and use PowerBuilder 10.5 ). Now there are a couple of columns which can have different colours and I want to see those colours when selecting a row. However I don't know how to deselect these columns and have the first couple of columns remain selected.
The highlight function in our application just does a dw.selectrow( x, true ).

Regards,
Marinus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll get what you want using `selectrow`. If you don't need multiple selections you could change the background of the current row with an expression in the datawindow. If you want some columns to stay normal you could do that with a rectangle behind the ones you want to highlight instead of changing the row color. If you need multiple rows highlighted you will have to simulate multi-select by adding a dummy column and using that to control the background, and of course you need to handle the selecting and deselecting in the `clicked` event. If you've got code that deals with selected rows you'll have to change them to use the new scheme, for example by checking the value in your dummy column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SelectRow(), maybe use of SetRowFocusIndicator() would help. IIRC (it's been pretty close to decade**s** since I've used it), it disables the row colouring in favour of the new method.

The other way that comes to mind is setting an expression for background colour that uses GetRow() and CurrentRow(). This wouldn't be my first choice, as it doesn't let users with vision impairment choose their colours through standard Windows colour selection to something they can deal with, but if you're dead set on colour indications on selective columns, this would be the way to go.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: That's a good point about accessibility. One way to keep it accessible is to use the `Highlight` and `Highlight Text` system colors for the background and text, respectively of the items you're highlighting. Another way is to provide a way for the user to select the colors the application uses, if it isn't using the system colors. For the columns that the OP wants to keep unhighlighted, if they are using color to indicate something, the information should also be shown another way, such as in microhelp. (If you're required to be compliant, it's mandatory).